# Why does my wine taste salty?

Tags: fermentation, taste, aftertaste

I’ve been making regular batches of pomegranate wine. The latest batch fermented faster than usual due to ambient heat increase. However the result has a salty taste. What would be the cause of that and how could I relive or mask that taste?

Answer (score 1):

This is usually from overdose of campden tablets / potassium metabisulfite.

Usually the only practical solution is dilution.

Comment: Ah! Well I didn’t use any. So that would rule that cause out. Thanks though.